# Unable to attach or mount volumes: timed out waiting for the condition - AKS Solr Server error

Tags: kubernetes, solr, azure-aks

I'm trying to run a solr server pod on my AKS cluster, but it keeps throwing an error saying - `Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[backup-repository-solr-backup], unattached volumes=[backup-repository-solr-backup kube-api-access-mhz4q solr-xml scgnfs-solr-pvc]: timed out waiting for the condition`. I have deployed the cluster, volume mounts and other resources using Terraform.

Some of the kubectl outputs are as shown -

```
$ kubectl get pods -n <namespace>

NAME                                               READY   STATUS     RESTARTS        AGE
apache-solr-server-solrcloud-0                     0/1     Init:0/1   0               3d14h
apache-solr-server-solrcloud-1                     0/1     Init:0/1   0               3d14h
apache-solr-server-solrcloud-2                     0/1     Init:0/1   0               3d14h
apache-solr-server-solrcloud-zookeeper-0           1/1     Running    0               3d14h
apache-solr-server-solrcloud-zookeeper-1           1/1     Running    1 (3d14h ago)   3d14h
apache-solr-server-solrcloud-zookeeper-2           1/1     Running    4 (25h ago)     3d14h
solr-operator-7c6d46db-qsp4t                       1/1     Running    0               3d14h
solr-operator-zookeeper-operator-cfc5d5d59-4hggr   1/1     Running    0               3d14h
```

```
$ kubectl describe pod <pod_name> -n <namespace>

Name:             apache-solr-server-solrcloud-0
Namespace:        cs-solr
Priority:         0
Service Account:  default
Node:             aks-appsv1-14790217-vmss000010/172.21.145.100
Start Time:       Fri, 10 Nov 2023 21:16:32 +0530
Labels:           app.kubernetes.io/instance=apache-solr-server
                  app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
                  app.kubernetes.io/name=solr
                  app.kubernetes.io/version=8.11.1
                  controller-revision-hash=apache-solr-server-solrcloud-c9cd4b88c
                  helm.sh/chart=solr-0.8.0
                  solr-cloud=apache-solr-server
                  statefulset.kubernetes.io/pod-name=apache-solr-server-solrcloud-0
                  technology=solr-cloud
Annotations:      solr.apache.org/backupRepositories: solr-backup
                  solr.apache.org/solrXmlMd5: 28062a041f9071bd95bcf3b0c9ce01b7
Status:           Pending
IP:
IPs:              <none>
Controlled By:    StatefulSet/apache-solr-server-solrcloud
Init Containers:
  cp-solr-xml:
    Container ID:
    Image:         library/busybox:1.28.0-glibc
    Image ID:
    Port:          <none>
    Host Port:     <none>
    Command:
      sh
      -c
      cp /tmp/solr.xml /tmp-config/solr.xml && addgroup -g 8983 solr && adduser -u 8983 -G solr -H -D solr && (su solr -c 'test -w /var/solr/data/backup-restore/solr-backup' || chown -R 8983:8983 /var/solr/data/backup-restore/solr-backup)
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       PodInitializing
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Limits:
      cpu:     50e-3
      memory:  50M
    Requests:
      cpu:        50e-3
      memory:     50M
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:
      /tmp from solr-xml (rw)
      /tmp-config from scgnfs-solr-pvc (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-mhz4q (ro)
      /var/solr/data/backup-restore/solr-backup from backup-repository-solr-backup (rw,path="cloud/apache-solr-server")
Containers:
  solrcloud-node:
    Container ID:
    Image:          solr:8.11
    Image ID:
    Port:           8983/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       PodInitializing
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Liveness:       http-get http://:8983/solr/admin/info/system delay=0s timeout=1s period=20s #success=1 #failure=3
    Readiness:      http-get http://:8983/solr/admin/info/health delay=0s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=2
    Startup:        http-get http://:8983/solr/admin/info/system delay=10s timeout=1s period=5s #success=1 #failure=10
    Environment:
      SOLR_JAVA_MEM:        -Xms1g -Xmx2g
      SOLR_HOME:            /var/solr/data
      SOLR_PORT:            8983
      SOLR_NODE_PORT:       8983
      SOLR_PORT_ADVERTISE:  8983
      POD_HOSTNAME:         apache-solr-server-solrcloud-0 (v1:metadata.name)
      POD_NAME:             apache-solr-server-solrcloud-0 (v1:metadata.name)
      POD_IP:                (v1:status.podIP)
      POD_NAMESPACE:        cs-solr (v1:metadata.namespace)
      SOLR_HOST:            $(POD_NAME).apache-solr-server-solrcloud-headless.cs-solr
      SOLR_LOG_LEVEL:       INFO
      GC_TUNE:
      SOLR_STOP_WAIT:       55
      ZK_HOST:              apache-solr-server-solrcloud-zookeeper-0.apache-solr-server-solrcloud-zookeeper-headless.cs-solr.svc.cluster.local:2181,apache-solr-server-solrcloud-zookeeper-1.apache-solr-server-solrcloud-zookeeper-headless.cs-solr.svc.cluster.local:2181,apache-solr-server-solrcloud-zookeeper-2.apache-solr-server-solrcloud-zookeeper-headless.cs-solr.svc.cluster.local:2181/
      ZK_CHROOT:            /
      ZK_SERVER:            apache-solr-server-solrcloud-zookeeper-0.apache-solr-server-solrcloud-zookeeper-headless.cs-solr.svc.cluster.local:2181,apache-solr-server-solrcloud-zookeeper-1.apache-solr-server-solrcloud-zookeeper-headless.cs-solr.svc.cluster.local:2181,apache-solr-server-solrcloud-zookeeper-2.apache-solr-server-solrcloud-zookeeper-headless.cs-solr.svc.cluster.local:2181
      SOLR_OPTS:            -DhostPort=$(SOLR_NODE_PORT)
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-mhz4q (ro)
      /var/solr/data from scgnfs-solr-pvc (rw)
      /var/solr/data/backup-restore/solr-backup from backup-repository-solr-backup (rw,path="cloud/apache-solr-server")
Readiness Gates:
  Type                           Status
  solr.apache.org/isNotStopped   True
Conditions:
  Type                           Status
  solr.apache.org/isNotStopped   True
  Initialized                    False
  Ready                          False
  ContainersReady                False
  PodScheduled                   True
Volumes:
  scgnfs-solr-pvc:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  scgnfs-solr-pvc-apache-solr-server-solrcloud-0
    ReadOnly:   false
  solr-xml:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      apache-solr-server-solrcloud-configmap
    Optional:  false
  backup-repository-solr-backup:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  scgnfs-solr-pvc
    ReadOnly:   false
  kube-api-access-mhz4q:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   Burstable
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/memory-pressure:NoSchedule op=Exists
                             node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason       Age                      From     Message
  ----     ------       ----                     ----     -------
  Warning  FailedMount  19m (x979 over 3d13h)    kubelet  Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[backup-repository-solr-backup], unattached volumes=[solr-xml scgnfs-solr-pvc backup-repository-solr-backup kube-api-access-mhz4q]: timed out waiting for the condition
  Warning  FailedMount  10m (x437 over 3d14h)    kubelet  Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[backup-repository-solr-backup], unattached volumes=[scgnfs-solr-pvc backup-repository-solr-backup kube-api-access-mhz4q solr-xml]: timed out waiting for the condition
  Warning  FailedMount  3m29s (x431 over 3d13h)  kubelet  Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[backup-repository-solr-backup], unattached volumes=[backup-repository-solr-backup kube-api-access-mhz4q solr-xml scgnfs-solr-pvc]: timed out waiting for the condition
```

```
$ kubectl get pvc -n <namespace>

NAME                                             STATUS   VOLUME                                     CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS            AGE
data-apache-solr-server-solrcloud-zookeeper-0    Bound    pvc-a520af21-4084-4af5-b954-4613697a43ac   20Gi       RWO            default                 3d14h
data-apache-solr-server-solrcloud-zookeeper-1    Bound    pvc-3f27a00f-6577-4126-a014-f13c5ab4b881   20Gi       RWO            default                 3d14h
data-apache-solr-server-solrcloud-zookeeper-2    Bound    pvc-5e9a1e38-7f74-4270-9ac6-02df453190e4   20Gi       RWO            default                 3d14h
scgnfs-solr-pvc                                  Bound    scgnfs-solr-pv                             100        RWX            azurefile-csi-premium   3d15h
scgnfs-solr-pvc-apache-solr-server-solrcloud-0   Bound    pvc-ba419a5f-f634-4aa5-97f4-01a6066bb227   100Gi      RWO            azurefile-csi-premium   3d14h
scgnfs-solr-pvc-apache-solr-server-solrcloud-1   Bound    pvc-2acf3702-3e38-4c89-9366-7cd8336aee88   100Gi      RWO            azurefile-csi-premium   3d14h
scgnfs-solr-pvc-apache-solr-server-solrcloud-2   Bound    pvc-c13b240b-e133-46a5-b2ba-50f12d0aea07   100Gi      RWO            azurefile-csi-premium   3d14h
```

```
$ kubectl describe pvc scgnfs-solr-pvc -n <namespace>

Name:          scgnfs-solr-pvc
Namespace:     cs-solr
StorageClass:  azurefile-csi-premium
Status:        Bound
Volume:        scgnfs-solr-pv
Labels:        <none>
Annotations:   pv.kubernetes.io/bind-completed: yes
Finalizers:    [kubernetes.io/pvc-protection]
Capacity:      100
Access Modes:  RWX
VolumeMode:    Filesystem
Used By:       apache-solr-server-solrcloud-0
               apache-solr-server-solrcloud-1
               apache-solr-server-solrcloud-2
Events:        <none>
```

The values.yaml file passed while configuring the solr-server helm chart -

```
version: 0.8.0
backupRepositories:
    - name: "solr-backup"
      volume:
        source:
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: "scgnfs-solr-pvc"
dataStorage:
   type: persistent 
   capacity: 100Gi 
   persistent:
     pvc:
       name: scgnfs-solr-pvc
       storageClassName: azurefile-csi-premium
resources:
  limits:
    cpu: 4000m
    memory: 4G
```

The PVC for the backup repository is same as the PVC for solr-server. Is that an issue? I don't know where the issue is. The PVs and PVCs are all seemed to be successfully applied.

Can anyone help me where I'm wrong exactly? Thanks in advance.

**Edit1**: I created a different PV/PVC for backupRepository but that also gave the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to figure out the reason for the error. It turns out that the solr backup repository requires only a PVC and not the corresponding PV. It creates its own volume. I was earlier creating a PV and mapping this "scgnfs-solr-pvc" to that PV and then passing this pvc for the backup repository which is why the pvc was unable to attach to the volume solr was creating for the backup repository. You don't have to map this pvc with any pv. Create a standalone pvc without any volume and attach it to the backup repository and the pods will start running.

Answer (score 0):

The event logs indicate that the kubelet is having trouble attaching or mounting volumes for your Solr pods and kubelet is timing out.
Please verify if the storage class is installed and configured correctly.

```
kubectl get pods -n kube-system | grep azurefile
```

and

```
kubectl get storageclasses
```

Here it is azurefile-csi-premium.
[image]
I believe there is a problem with the provisioner.
[image]

I am using similar configuration with helm to setup Solr on aks and it is working.
[image]

```
kubectl get pods
```

[image]

Would suggest you verify the pv associated with the pvc are provisioned correctly and azure file storage can access it and also verify if the Azure File CSI driver is configured correctly in your cluster as shown above.

You can refer to similar issue on

[kubernetes QnA Forum](https://discuss.kubernetes.io/t/unable-to-attach-or-mount-volumes-unmounted-volumes-code-storage/13921/3)

[MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/azure-kubernetes/fail-to-mount-azure-disk-volume)

[GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/AKS/issues/2877)

[Running Solr on kubernetes](https://lucidworks.com/post/running-solr-on-kubernetes-part-1/)

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply. The solr-operator and zookeeper pods are running for me also. It's the solr-cloud pods that are in init state and are unable to attach to the volumes. The CSI driver is also configured correctly as per the output you've mentioned. The PV and PVC are also provisioned correctly and the file storage is also bound to it.

Comment: If the CSI driver, PVs and PVCs are configured correctly then there shouldn't be any blocker. All the pods - the operator, zookeeper pods along with the solr cloud pods should be up as you can see here https://i.imgur.com/cli5nuu.png. You can also refer to this document for further clarity- https://apache.github.io/solr-operator/docs/local_tutorial.html

Comment: So the thing is, I removed the backup repositories configuration and just created the solr-server pvcs and the pods are up. But as soon as I attached a backup repository to one of the pods, that pod immediately went back to the pending state with the same error as mentioned in the original post. I'd highly appreciate any explanation or help on this. Thanks.